# Can I use Spark for custom computation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have some (200ish) large zip files (some >1GB) that should be unzipped and processed using Python geo- and imageprocessing libraries. The results will be written as new files in FileStore, and later used for ML tasks in Databricks.

What would the general approach be, if I want to exploit the Spark cluster processing power? I'm thinking of adding the filenames to a DataFrame, and using user defined functions to process them via Select or similar. I believe I should be able to make this run in parallel on the cluster, where the workers will get just the filename, and then load the files locally.

Is this reasonable, or is there some completely different direction I should go?

Update - Or maybe like this:

```
zipfiles = ...

def f(x):
  print("Processing " + x)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('myApp').getOrCreate()
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(zipfiles)
rdd.foreach(f)
```

Update 2:
For anyone doing this. Since Spark by default will reserve almost all available memory you might have to reduce that with this setting: spark.executor.memory 1g
Or you might run out of memory quickly on the worker.

Comment: I think that won't work because the files won't be on the workers, so you won't be able to find and process them. Spark is for data processing, data organized in dataframe. What you want to do is multrithreading, there are tons of python libs for that. But spark is not one of them.

Comment: I can enumerate the files in dbfs on the master, so I believe the workers should be able to load too?

Comment: I'd like to exploit the cluster workers, not just run multithreaded on a single machine.

Comment: from my experience, it's not gonna work, and even if somehow you make it work (which i'd like to see then) it won't be efficient because spark is not made for that. Just take a look at the available functions for dataframe. None of them handle files. It's a data engineering framework. You'll be way better using pure python process. Also, knowing how map/reduce works should make you understand that working on files this way is not possible.

Comment: Hi Steven - it seems this does work just fine. See my update to the question. My User Defined Function loads files from DBFS and processes them, then writes results back to DBSF. Concurrency is controlled by the parallelize() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Spark as a generic-parallel-processing engine, give or take some serialization issues. For example, in one project I've used spark to scan many bloom filters in parallel, and random-access indexed files where the bloom filters returned positive. Most likely you will need to use the RDD api for such tailor made solutions.

Comment: It does seem to work just fine so far, thanks. I'm using RDD and parallelize.